# How to get value inside a bytes data type?

Tags: python, pandas

i have data that seems to be bytes format. I did `type(data)`and get `bytes`. I would like from this get `"recordsFiltered":84` and especially the number 84.

How should it be possible ?

I tried data['recordsFiltered'] but get an error message:

```
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

and when I tried data[0] I get a number which is 123 that I do not understand

My data looks like:

```
b'{"draw":2,"recordsTotal":84,"recordsFiltered":84,"data":[{"ID_Produit":77581,"cTypeFinancialItem":1,"cClasseFinancialItem":0,"sTypeFinancialObject":"F","checkbox":null,"sNom":"ACATIS Fair Value Deutschland ELM A","sURL":"/Produit/77581","sNomManager":"Acatis Investment","sNomTypeFinancialObject":"Fonds","sGroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic":"Actions Europe","sGroupeCat_rng1":"Actions","sCodeISIN":"LU0158903558","nVL":315.98,"sCurrency":"EUR","nStarRating":2,"nScore":48,"nRetYTD":-5.84,"nRet1a":-10.64,"nRet3a":3.18,"nRet5a":0.91,"nRet1c":-8.16,"nRet3c":6.08,"nRet1j":0.87,"nRet1m":8.36,"nRet3m":-2.3,"nRet6m":-9.88,"nRet5c":19.49,"nRet8c":12.4,"nVolat1a":17.22,"nVolat3a":19.69,"nVolat5a":25.51,"nSharpe1a":-0.78,"nSharpe3a":0.13,"nSharpe5a":0.03,"nPerteMax1a":24.68,"nPerteMax3a":37.94,"nPerteMax5a":43.39,"nSortino1a":-1.13,"nSortino3a":0.19,"nSortino5a":0.04,"nIr1A":-1.98,"nIr3A":-0.16,"nIr5A":-0.1,"nMinInvest":0.0,"nFraisGestion":1.84,"nFraisEntree":5.5,"nFraisSortie":0.0,"dtRet":"2023-11-17","dtRetMonth":"2023-10-31","bFerme":false,"nIntensiteESG":3,"nActifEur":57733074.45,"nActifDiffEUR1m":6065933.77,"nActifDiffEUR3m":-5048473.27,"nActifDiffEUR6m":-8385485.26,"nActifDiffEUR1A":-11977507.97,"nActifCompartimentEUR":60112310.91,"nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1m":6310580.94,"nActifCompartimentDiffEUR3m":-8582414.99,"nActifCompartimentDiffEUR6m":-13864156.95,"nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1A":-17570327.0,"nCollecteCompartiment1m":47050.56,"nCollecteCompartiment3m":-4506369.69,"nCollecteCompartiment6m":-7631976.75,"nCollecteCompartimentYTD":-9745686.39,"nCollecteCompartiment1A":-9624455.26,"nCollecteCompartiment3A":-12990833.32,"nCollecteRet1m":null,"nCollecteRet3m":null,"nCollecteRet6m":null,"nCollecteRetYTD":null,"nCollecteRet1A":null,"nCollecteRet3A":null,"nCollecteCompartimentRet1m":0.09,"nCollecteCompartimentRet3m":-6.56,"nCollecteCompartimentRet6m":-10.32,"nCollecteCompartimentRetYTD":-13.21,"nCollecteCompartimentRet1A":-12.39,"nCollecteCompartimentRet3A":-17.84,"isESG":true,"sArticleSFDR":"Article 9","nIntensiteISR":3,"nESG_Environnement":3,"nESG_Social":3,"nESG_Gouvernance":3,"nNbLabels":1,"sProspectusUrl":"/Produit/Post/DownloadDocument?subFolder=28%2f121&documentName=6C3D0C97-F9BD-46ED-93B0-EAA1D47C71B3&downloadFileName=ACATIS+Fair+Value+Deutschland+ELM+A_LU0158903558.pdf","sUrlMainDocument":"/Produit/Post/DownloadDocument?subFolder=26%5c149&documentName=D7B5088B-F0D9-4F7A-98C8-A3E6630B2DAE&downloadFileName=ACATIS+Fair+Value+Deutschland+ELM+A_LU0158903558.pdf","isMainDocumentAccessible":false},
```

Comment: That's where your 123 is coming from: https://www.ascii-code.com/123

Comment: Is this a response from an API, for which you posted `response.content`? this looks like JSON (you need to decode it first)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your data resembles json, but a broken one - the ending for what you posted is

```
..."isMainDocumentAccessible":false},'
```

In order for it to be valid JSON, it'd have to end like that:

```
..."isMainDocumentAccessible":false}]}'
```

The 123 you are seeing with `data[0]` is an ascii value of character at that position, `{` - https://www.ascii-code.com/123

With fixed JSON though, it's very easy to convert that into Python dictionary and directly access all the information you need:

```
import json

data = b'...'

print(json.loads(data)['recordsTotal']) # 84
```

Comment: Most likely OP just need to use `response.json()` or `json.loads(response.text)`... i.e. this is more or less XY question

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works:

```
import json 
json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))['recordsFiltered']
```